# Django Infinite scroll using Django Paginate repeating the queryset

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-pagination

**Intro:** I am using the the below link to add infinite scroll to my project https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html

below is the github code for that link
https://github.com/sibtc/simple-infinite-scroll

The link shows how to add infinite scroll to both `function based views` and `class based views`. I have added this to my function based view and it works perfect.

**The problem:** I have **8 posts** in my post-list which is a `class-based view`. After I add `paginate_by = 3` I can only see 3 posts of the 8 posts. Everytime I scroll down these 3 posts keep repeating in an infinite loop

**My Views:**

```
class Postlist(SelectRelatedMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')
    paginate_by = 3
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
         queryset = super(Postlist, self).get_queryset().order_by('-created_at')
         query = self.request.GET.get('q')
         if query:
             queryset = queryset.filter(
             Q(title__icontains=query)|
             Q(user__username__iexact=query)|
             Q(user__first_name__iexact=query)|
            Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)

        )
          return queryset
```

**My Base.html:** (I have the below files in JS folder they worked for my FBV)

```
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
```

**My post_list.html:**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="infinite-container">
        {% for post in post_list %}
        <div class="infinite-item">
            {% include "posts/_post.html" %} <!---This code is good---->
        </div>
        {% empty %}
               some code    
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
        Loading...
    </div>

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ post_list.next_page_number }}">More</a>
    {% endif %}

</div>

{% block javascript %}
  <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
      }
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the templates I replaced `post_list` with `page_obj` see below code. That did it

```
{% if post_list.has_next %}
   <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
{% endif %}
```